# Swing font skewing with Redhat CentOS

Tags: java, swing, layout, fonts

I have created a Swing application on my Windows 7-64bit machine and am now trying to get it to work correctly on a Linux box running Redhat CentOS. The code is below:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SwingExample implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // Create the window
        JFrame f = new JFrame ("Hello, World!");
        // Sets the behavior for when the window is closed
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // add a label and a button
        f.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Hello, world!"));
        f.getContentPane().add(new JButton("Press me!"));
        // arrange the components inside the window
        f.pack();
        //By default, the window is not visible. Make it visible.
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingExample se = new SwingExample();
        // Schedules the application to be run at the correct time in the event queue.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(se);
    }
}
```

On my windows box, ran through Eclipse, this looks fine. However when I run the same code on the Linux box, like so:

[image]

As you can see, the text inside the title is fine, but the font for the button is skewed.
Anyone have ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You're adding both components to the `CENTER` of the frame's default `BorderLayout`. Try adding one to `NORTH`. For example,

```
f.add(new JLabel("Hello, world!", JLabel.CENTER), BorderLayout.NORTH);
f.add(new JButton("Press me!"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```